# How to redirect audio output to input with JACK?

Tags: redirect, audio, microphone, jack

I want to redirect audio output from my USB headset (USB PnP Sound Device) to virtual line-in port (Line 1) created with Virtual Audio Cable. AFAIK, JACK can do that, but i'm new to JACK. I need to just select "USB PnP Sound Device" as input, and "Line 1" as output.

Where i need to specify these parameters in JACK?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
cat /dev/whateverHeadsetDevName > /dev/virtualLineInDevName &
```

?

Comment: That means i need to download Cygwin? Anyway, no. I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I had assumed a linux or Mac, in which case the command was intended to truly be an answer/solution.  I could have re-worded as, "Try ...", and should have.